# Mutliple ko.obersvable assigned to same reference - bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm amending some knockout code and I've encountered this :

```
this.edit = ko.observable();
this.selected = ko.observable();
this.clicked = ko.observable();
```

Assigning multiple references to the same ko.observable does not make sense to me. Is there a reason it is done in this way ?

I think it should just be something like :

```
this.genericName = ko.observable();
```

And then just use this.genericName wherever this.edit,this.selected or this.clicked are used.

Comment: If you want to observe three distinct values, you need three distinct observables. `ko.observable()` returns a new observable on each call.

Comment: This question does not make a whole lot of sense. It's missing essential information, please explain more closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ko.observable();` returns a single new observable property, unlike an object with as set of observable properties like model objects in Backbone. To have an object with multiple observable properties, you need to create multiple observables using the `ko.observable()` factory method.

You can see that they are independent:

```
var a = ko.observable();
var b = ko.observable();
a(1);
b(2);
console.log(a()); // prints 1
```